# Can I compile code from multiple languages together with LLVM?

Tags: compilation, llvm, multilingual

Can I write a program in two different languages and compile them together in one LLVM executable?

For example, part of my program is in C++, and part of it is in D.

Comment: the compiler is allowed to say _yes, maybe_ but the ABI will surely say _no no no_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not in the general case. Only if the languages are ABI-compatible. This is true for C and C++ to a very limited degree (`extern "C"` code from the C++ side), and much less so for other languages.

Comment: Shouldn't such compatibility be much easier if both languages are compiled with LLVM?

Comment: @VictorLyuboslavsky: if you invest extra work into it. Both Julia and Haskell (via GHC) compile to LLVM IR. It doesn't mean you can just call any Haskell function from Julia

Comment: @EliBendersky If they both compile to LLVM-IR, can the two IRs be combined using `llvm-link` and then be interpreted with `lli` successfully?

Comment: @mishr: no, it's not that simple. LLVM IR cannot represent any non-trivial data structures - this is the ABI, and the frontend handles this. So if you pass some object from one language to another, LLVM IR cannot magically know how to decompose the object in one language and rebuild it in another.